# DIR but select specific parts of file names

Tags: parsing, cmd, directory, command, names

I have the habit for years to use this very easy and convenient `.BAT` file to create a simple `TXT` file of all my files in a directory:

```
dir *.* > LIST.TXT
```

but the result includes many pieces of information that I don't need

Now I have many files in a directory in this way:

```
file 01 [shYddYJQIGfffY].xyz
second file 00008 [shYddYJQIfGf11dfzrffY].exe
filex [shGffY].sys
file that i don't need.txt
many other files that i don't need.bat
```

1/ which command line can  I use with DIR (or anything else) to have in the final LIST.txt files only those information? only the value between `[` and `]`

Expected result:

```
shYddYJQIGfffY
shYddYJQIfGf11dfzrffY
shGffY
```

2/ how to edit the `.BAT` file to add the string `MYRESULT` before each of those results, like:

```
MYRESULT shYddYJQIGfffY
MYRESULT shYddYJQIfGf11dfzrffY
MYRESULT shGffY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop (see `for /?`):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('dir /b *[*].*') do echo MYRESULT %%a
```

This `for /f` loop takes the output of `dir /b *[*].*` (filtering for relevant files, **b**are format) line per line and splits it into three parts, first token the part before the first `[`, token2 the part between `[` and `]`. and a third part after that. You need the second token only. Then just echo the string together with the extracted substring, done.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Super impressive answer. Exactly what I was looking for! I already found a way with Excel, convert column with [ then ], then concat with MYRESULT, copy past, etc Your answer is 1000 times faster. I really hope that one day me too I can understand better those very strong DOS powerful functions. I don't know why each time I try to search online a solution with DOS i can almost never find it. And at the end instead of loosing more time on google I find other solutions with excel. Thanks again a lot!

Comment: Don't search for DOS. It's an ancient command-line based operating system The Windows Command line is a completely different pair of boots. Use `cmd` as search criteria instead.